# M210 RTK V2 - OSDK 3.8/3.8.1 and Video stream not working (samples not working)

Tags: dji-sdk

I have successfully executed all the OSDK 3.8/3.8.1 samples regarding telemetry, FPV camera, etc. with an M210 RTK V2 (Frimware 1.0.0450) and a Zenmuse X4S. However, I have tested OSDK 3.8 and 3.8.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 and I have not succeed with the pre-made main camera samples (in this case, the `camera-stream-callback-sample` for retrieving the main camera image).

The problem is that the (OSDK 3.8.1) `camera-stream-callback-sample` is not working (RC turned ON). It is giving the following error:

```
Please enter the type of camera stream you want to view
m: Main Camera
f: FPV  Camera
m
Read App ID
User Configuration read successfully. 


STATUS/1 @ init, L55: Attempting to open device /dev/ttyUSB0 with baudrate 921600...

STATUS/1 @ init, L65: ...Serial started successfully.

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L727: Device Serial No. = 1DADG3E00100TW

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L729: Hardware = PM420

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L730: Firmware = 3.4.3.31

ERRORLOG/1 @ initVirtualRC, L1103: Virtual RC is not supported on this platform!

STATUS/1 @ init, L49: Looking for USB device...

STATUS/1 @ init, L65: Found 13 USB devices, identifying DJI device...

STATUS/1 @ init, L83: Found a DJI device...

STATUS/1 @ init, L96: Attempting to open DJI USB device...

STATUS/1 @ init, L134: ...DJI USB device started successfully.

STATUS/1 @ activate, L1313: version 0x304031F

STATUS/1 @ activate, L1326: 
STATUS/1 @ verify, L244: Verify subscription successful.
STATUS/1 @ initGimbal, L890: Checking if gimbal is connected ...
STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L350: Start package 0 result: 0.
STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L352: Package 0 info: freq=50, nTopics=1.

STATUS/1 @ removePackage, L468: Remove package 0 successful.
STATUS/1 @ init, L55: Attempting to open device  with baudrate 230400...

ERRORLOG/1 @ _serialOpen, L175: cannot open device 

ERRORLOG/1 @ init, L60: ...Failed to start serial

STATUS/1 @ keep_camera_x5s_state, L44: Sending heart beat

ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: Port closed
STATUS/1 Connect to MAIN_CAMERA successful

STATUS/1 All components for decoding initialized ...

STATUS/1 User callback thread created successfully!

STATUS/1 **** MAIN_CAMERA data reading thread start! ****

STATUS/1 ****** Decoder Callback Thread Start ******

ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 @ keep_camera_x5s_state, L44: 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 @ keep_camera_x5s_state, L44: 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 @ keep_camera_x5s_state, L44: 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 @ keep_camera_x5s_state, L44: 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189: 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 
STATUS/1 @ keep_camera_x5s_state, L44: 
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L189:
```

With OSDK 3.8, the result is the following

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I don't know what else to do, since it is official OSDK with supported M210RTK V2 and Zenmuse X4S. I have tested the FPV and it works successfully.

Can anybody provide some help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: haven`t try 3.8 inbuild stream yet.  Tmr is holiday, if you want I can help you check on it on Thursday

Comment: Ok, thank you. It is happening with both 3.8 and 3.8.1 (with M210 RTK V2 and Zenmuse X4S on Ubuntu 16.04). Hope we can find a solution.

Comment: sry couldnt do the test have m210 but some1 took the remote away. cant link without it. will get it tmr

Comment: I have already solved it, thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: In Ubuntu 16.04 and OSDK 3.8.1 with M210 RTK V2 (all the checklist met and the RC turned on) the sample has to be called like this:

`./camera-stream-callback-sample UserConfig.txt /dev/ttyACM0`

Hope it helps.

Comment: previous all are connected by "./camera-stream-callback-sample UserConfig.txt"